# Coredata structure for one-to-many or many-to-many relationship without duplicates

Tags: swift, core-data, persistence

Im working on an app which provides audios to its users. These audios are called sessions. There are series/Playlists with multiple sessions. Then there are Content Groups with multiple sessions, playlist, series. I want to store the data in core data.

I have created an entity as `ListItem` which will be used for series, playlists and sessions with an attribute "type"(used to distinguish the type of content) and itemUID with "type+itemID" this itemUID will be unique despite have the same itemID. I have set constraint on ListItem for "itemUID" to avoid duplication.

I have also created ``ContentGroup``` entity with to-many relation with ListItem. The reason for many to many is one content can point to many listItems and listItems can have many groups.

There are cases when a particular playlist/ session can be present in multiple groups. I don't want to create duplicate entries for such items. I have set the mergerPolicy to `mergeByPropertyStoreTrumpMergePolicyType`   I am also using parent and child viewcontext to avoid blocking main queue. Below is the code:

```
lazy var mainQueueViewContext: NSManagedObjectContext = {
       let context = persistentContainer.viewContext
            context.mergePolicy = NSMergePolicy(merge: .mergeByPropertyStoreTrumpMergePolicyType)
        return context
    }()
    
    lazy var privateQueueViewContext: NSManagedObjectContext = {
        let childContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .privateQueueConcurrencyType)
        childContext.mergePolicy = NSMergePolicy(merge: .mergeByPropertyStoreTrumpMergePolicyType)
        return childContext
    }()
private override init() {
        super.init()
        privateQueueViewContext.parent = mainQueueViewContext
    }
```

All the changes are written on `privateQueueViewContext`. However, when the app moves to BG, the `save()` method on `mainQueueViewContext` the app crashes or don't save the data. The errors are:

> Dangling reference to an invalid object.=null, NSValidationErrorValue=Relationship 'contents'

If I remove merpolicy for Parent context, I get this error:

> NSConstraintConflict for constraint (\n    itemUID\n)

What did I do wrong here? Did I miss anything?